# '[ngTemplateOutet]' is working but '*ngTemplateOutlet' is not

Tags: angular, typescript

I tried to make a component which is using ngTemplateOutlet to pick ng-template, but I just can't figure out why *ngTemplateOutlet is not working here(but [ngTemplateOutlet] is working).

here is my code

demo-frame.component.html:

```html
<div class="frame-wrapper">
  <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="(windowWidth < 480)? this.realView : this.shelledView">
    <ng-template #realView>
      realView work!!
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #shelledView>
      shelledView work!!
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

demo-frame.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demo-frame',
  templateUrl: './demo-frame.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo-frame.component.scss']
})
export class DemoFrameComponent implements OnInit {

  public windowWidth : number;
  @ViewChild('realView') realView : TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('shelledView') shelledView : TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { }

  getWindowWidth(){
    this.windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    this.getWindowWidth();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getWindowWidth();
  }

}
```

actually I am new to Angular : ( 
Just need someone to point out my mistake

Comment: "not working" is useless. Show the actual usage and the behavior encountered

Comment: @AluanHaddad
but it just showed nothing when I use *ngTemplateOutlet, there was even no cosole error

Answer (score 3):

If a directive starts with (*) asterisk prefix which means It's structural directive in angular.
Behind the scene what angular will do is wrap your host element inside ng-template. So in your case the whole ng-container will be wrapped inside ng-template like below code, so In your code viewChild was not initialised, that's why it's not working.

```
<div class="frame-wrapper">
  <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="(windowWidth < 480)? this.realView : this.shelledView">
    <ng-container>
    <ng-template #realView>
      realView work!!
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #shelledView>
      shelledView work!!
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

[For more info check this](http://%20%20%20[1]:%20https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-asterisk--prefix)

Comment: Thank U :D. I think I got it. So I guess... if i still want to use *ngTemplateOutlet here, I have to move those ng-template out of the ng-container.